# Pycharm attaching to process looping

Tags: python, pycharm, curses

I'm trying to use "Attach to Local Process" to debug a curses application inside my terminal, for some reason it finds the process correctly, but loops infinitely. I've tried `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, I've made sure that the interpreter of my Pycharm project is the same has the one running my application on my terminal, but to no avail. Also, there's breakpoints inside my code.

[image]